# Fancybox launch from Google Maps marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps, click, fancybox, marker

I have been trying to get a Fancybox window to launch when a GoogleMap marker is clicked. I've checked out this question [Calling Fancybox from Event Listener in Google Maps Instead of Default Infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801488/calling-fancybox-from-event-listener-in-google-maps-instead-of-default-infowindo) but the solution doesn't seem to work for me.

The page I'm working on is this: http://halal-helvetica.ch/m/

(You'll have to find Switzerland on the map to find some markers)

When you click on a marker the "loading" thing comes up and goes on continuously without loading the content from the provided url (it should display "lorem ipsum dolor...").

Can anyone help? It looks like a jQuery/Ajax issue to me, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Chrome error console says "XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://www.halal-helvetica.ch/m/fancybox-content.php`. Origin `http://halal-helvetica.ch` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.". Sounds like a header problem. I suggest you redirect the user to the `www.` version of your site and the problem should theoretically be solved.

Also, upon Googling "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains).

Comment: Thank you very much Nick - it seems to be the "www" problem that you mention.

If i access the site from the www-prefixed URL Fancybox pops up as expected.

I tried to debug using Firebug, but didn't see this specific error. 

Cheers!