# Fancybox iframe from Google Map V3 marker click

Tags: google-maps-api-3, fancybox, google-maps-markers, lightbox

I have a Google Map (v3) that I am placing several markers into, and want to be able to click on the markers and pull up a Fancybox iFrame. I can't figure out how to pull the URL from the marker into Fancybox.

I can see the Fancybox firing - the popup window appears breifly and then the link is pulled up as a new page over top of the current page.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
 var sites = [
['Mount Evans', 39.58108, -105.63535, 4, 'www.myurl-1.com'],
['Irving Homestead', 40.315939, -105.440630, 2, 'wwww.myurl-2.com'],
['Badlands National Park', 43.785890, -101.90175, 1, 'www.myurl-3.com'],
['Flatirons in the Spring', 39.99948, -105.28370, 3, 'www.myurl-4.com']
];

function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            url: sites[4]
        });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {     
        $.fancybox({
            href : function() {
                    window.location.href = marker.url;
              },
            width : 1000,
            maxHeight   : 666,
            fitToView   : true,
            autoSize    : false,
            type: 'iframe',
            padding: 0,
            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,
            aspectRatio : true,
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,
            closeClick : true,
            iframe : { scrolling : 'no'
            },
            preload   : true
        });
    });

    }

}
```

Comment: I solved it:  $.fancybox({href : sites[4]});

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Fancybox from Event Listener in Google Maps Instead of Default Infowindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801488/calling-fancybox-from-event-listener-in-google-maps-instead-of-default-infowindo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code I used to solve this:

```
    var sites = [
    ['Mount Evans', 39.58108, -105.63535, 4, 'www.myurl-1.com'],
    ['Irving Homestead', 40.315939, -105.440630, 2, 'wwww.myurl-2.com'],
    ['Badlands National Park', 43.785890, -101.90175, 1, 'www.myurl-3.com'],
    ['Flatirons in the Spring', 39.99948, -105.28370, 3, 'www.myurl-4.com']
    ];

    function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            href: sites[4]
        });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {    
        $.fancybox({
            href : sites[4],
            width : 1000,
            maxHeight   : 666,
            fitToView   : true,
            autoSize    : false,
            type: 'iframe',
            padding: 0,
            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,
            aspectRatio : true,
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,
            closeClick : true,
            iframe : { scrolling : 'no'
            },
            preload   : true
        });
    });

    }

}
```

Just referenced href in the marker options and referred to in the fancybox call.

Answer (score 0):

Check also this post Open DIV as fancy box Google Map Marker

```
 $("a#fancyBoxLink").fancybox({
        'href'   : '#myDivID',
        'titleShow'  : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
    });
```

[Fancybox with Google Map Marker](http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/fancybox-on-google-map-marker-example.html)